# Document sub-arrays stored as duplicate values of the first entry in Mongo

Tags: arrays, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using angular-fullstack and Mongolabs when attempting to update any document sub-arrays the values that are stored in Mongolabs appear simply as duplicate values of the first element in the array.

The Mongoose schema is set as

```
techspecs: [{label: String, value: String, _id: false}],
```

When updating the payload appears correct and contains different values e.g.

```
techspecs: [{label: "Dimensions", value: "1200x800mm"}, {label:"Capacity", value: "532 l"}]
```

However in Mongolabs the values are stored as

```
"techspecs": [
        {
            "label": "Dimensions",
            "value": "1200x800mm"
        },
        {
            "label": "Dimensions",
            "value": "1200x800mm"
        }
    ],
```

If I have more value pairs it just keeps storing multiple duplicates of the first element.

The update is done using $resource through a factory service

```
angular.module('prototypeMeanApp')
  .factory('productAPI', ['$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('api/products/:id', {id: '@_id'}, {
        'update': { method:'PUT'},
        'create': { method:'POST'},
        'query' : {method:'GET', isArray:true}
      });         
    }
]);
```

In the controller it's being updated via the following function

```
$scope.updateProduct = function(form) {
  $scope.submitted = true;      
  var pId = $scope.product._id;
  if(form.$valid) {
    productAPI.update({id: pId}, {
          _id: pId,
          categoryid: $scope.currentcat[0]._id,
          brand: $scope.product.brand,
          model: $scope.product.model,
          heading: $scope.product.heading,
          description: $scope.product.description,
          price: $scope.product.price,
          techspecs: $scope.product.techspecs,
          lastmodified: Date.now()   
    }).$promise.then(function() {    
      console.log('Product updated');          
    }, function(err) {
      err = err.data;
      $scope.errors = {};
      angular.forEach(err.errors, function(error, field) {
        form[field].$setValidity('mongoose', false);
        $scope.errors[field] = error.message;            
      });
    });
```

And in the view

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="techspec in product.techspecs">
    <label class="control-label hidden-xs col-sm-3">Tech Spec #{{$index+1}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="controls">                                                     
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="techspec.label" class="form-control" placeholder="Label" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="controls">                                         
            <input data-ng-model="techspec.value" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Value"  />
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up a simple test with mean.io to verify that this possible to do and Mean.io successfully stored the document sub-arrays into Mongo. After this I compared the source and implementation methods for angular-fullstack and mean.io to see what was different.

In the end turned out to be the lodash method used in the update function.

angular-fullstack used `_.merge` whilst mean.io used `_.extend` after changing the angular-fullstack code to use `_.extend` the sub-arrays were correctly stored into MongoDB

For anyone else using angular-fullstack. Edit your server endpoint controller e.g. server/api/products/product.controller.js

Then find the function for update and replace the _.merge with _.extend e.g.

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Product.findById(req.params.id, function (err, product) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!product) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.extend(product, req.body);
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, product);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the issue I was having